# How many questions have been answered?

Tags: feature-request

The [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) page displays how many questions have been asked on SO. Wouldn't it be nice to show/know how many of those questions that were answered? *(marked accepted)*

That would tell users and visitors how useful this site is and how much it contributes to our fellow developers.

Here are a couple of examples how this could look. Any other ideas?

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: This information is available [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) already but guess you already know that and mean adding it into every site's Questions page as well?

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. But yeah, that's exactly what I meant =)

Comment: Wow so the 80% was a wild guess?

Comment: Heh, almost. Some head math with this number and the number from the  `unanswered` questions tab.

Comment: Do you mean unanswered as in "0-answers" or as in "no accepted answer".

Comment: I meant questions marked as accepted. Just having an answer doesn't tell you that much since it could be a faulty answer. Do I have the number wrong then?

Comment: If we turn the "x% answered" into a link to the unanswered question list, I'm all in!